# How to access variable outside of function scope

Tags: javascript

I am receiving data in my public folder file, which is `firebase-messaging-sw.js` from source code e.g main thread with postMessage method. I want to use that data received into messaging.onBackgroundMessage function. Here is my code:

```
self.addEventListener("message", event => {
  const messageData = event.data
  console.log(messageData)
})
messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  // const notification = new Notification(messageData[keywords][lang]![title], {
  //   body: messageData[keywords][lang]![body]
  // });
  storeMessage(payload.data);
});
```

I want to use that **messageData** into `messaging.onBackgroundMessage` function. I have tried declaring *let messageData* outside of function scopes but it doesn't work.

Comment: When you say " have tried declaring let messageData outside of function scopes but it doesn't work" can you give more details?  For example, a sample of code where you tried that, and what happened when you did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code snippet below, messageData is available in messaging.bar

So either your messageData variable isn't accessible, or the second event handler (onBackgroundMessage) is occurring before the first (message event)

```js
let self = {}, messaging = {}, messageData;

self.foo = (event => {
  messageData = event.data
  console.log(messageData)
})
messaging.bar = ((payload) => {
  // const notification = new Notification(messageData[keywords][lang]![title], {
  //   body: messageData[keywords][lang]![body]
  // });
//  storeMessage(payload.data);
  console.log(messageData);
});

var event = {};
event.data = "test";
self.foo(event);
messaging.bar();
```